# z-standardization for longitudinal data

Tags: standardization

I have data gathered at two time points, T1 and T2, from the same individuals. I would like to see whether scores improved from T1 to T2, in other words to measure growth. Each individual's score at each time point is actually made up of performance on several tests (a,b,c,d) that are measured on different scales and for the most part repeated across T1 and T2. Also, scores on (a,b,c,d) are highly correlated. Therefore, I plan to z-transform scores for each test and then combine z(a), z(b), z(c) and z(d) for each participant to get two composite scores: one at T1 and another at T2. Then I plan to compare the composite scores at T1 and T2 to assess growth.

The question I have is what mean and standard deviation to use for transforming (a,b,c,d). Specifically, because I want to measure growth from T1 to T2, the means and SDs used for standardization need to be the same for T1 and T2. One option is that I could use the mean and SD of each test at T1 to standardize scores for that test at both T1 and T2. Another option is to take the mean and SD of each test for T1 and T2 combined, and use that for z-standardization.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can provide a reason to prefer one option over the other.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to avoid z-standardization of longitudinal data for reasons explained here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4569815/

Instead, you can use Proportion of Maximum Scaling transformation (Little, T. D. (2013). Longitudinal structural equation modeling. Guilford press.) to get all measures to the same metric (also explained in the link above).

Good luck!

Comment: Can you add a full citation for "Little,2013" to make it easier for future readers to look up?